# Change Font Color

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors

I have created a Contact Form using someone else's coding. View it here - http://orchardhillsdesigns.com/contact_form/contactform.php. One small issue I have is the font color on "click to refresh". I know nothing about Javascript. I wrote to the deveoper but the email was returned and his copyright was 2008, so I assume he's gone.

I am paranoid to touch the script and mess it up.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need JavaScript for this. It's just plain and simple CSS.

```
a {color: #333;}
a:hover {color: #f0f0f0;}
a:active {color: #ccc;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jezen have already answered you but it seems that you aren't sure what to do with the CSS.

Ok, let's do it step by step. Here's the selector the anchor that says "Click to Refresh"

```
.short_explanation a {color: #ccc;}
.short_explanation a:hover {color: #f0f0f0;}
.short_explanation a:active {color: #ccc;}
```

Now where to put this ? I guess there's a file named contact.css for that contact form, open that file to edit it and paste the CSS below or above the other CSS rules in the file.